# Snow Leopard: Remove blue background for files in finder

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, finder, osx-leopard

I just upgraded from Tiger to Snow Leopard and I have been undoing all of the visual things that I don't like.

In the finder it highlights every other file with a blue background.  Anyone know how to remove that?

[image]

Comment: To any answerer who does a Google search, the 10.5 solution `defaults write com.apple.finder FXListViewStripes -bool FALSE` no longer works in 10.6.

Comment: @fideli, I think that you should make this an answer as it is useful.

Comment: No, it doesn't actually answer your question :) . A good answer might come up.